# JavaScript check field value based on variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an anchor like this:

```
<a href="#" rel="1 4 7 18 ">Anchor</a>
```

Where 'rel' attribute values are ids of some items.
Than I have a form with an input, where user should type an id and click submit button.
On submit button click I need to check the value of input like this:

```
var value = $('a').attr('rel'); // get anchor 'rel' ids
var uservalue = $('input[type='text']').val();
if ( uservalue == '1' || uservalue == '4' || uservalue == '7' || uservalue == '18') {
// however I need the line above are created dynamically based on 'value' var
  alert('The id exists');
  return false;
} else {
  return true;
}
```

So, the question is how to create a line below dynamically based on anchor 'rel' attribute values?!
This is the line:

```
if ( value == '1' || value == '4' || value == '7' || value == '18') {
```

Comment: what do you mean by "how to create a line", what do you need to do?

Comment: I need just check if typed value by user doesn't exist in anchor rel ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the thing by myself:

```
var value = $('a').attr('rel'); // get anchor 'rel' ids
var uservalue = $('input[type='text']').val();

if ( value.match(uservalue) ) {
  alert('The id exists');
  return false;
} else {
  return true;
}
```

It was just necessary to put a match function.
Match function matches any result of a string, not the equal one.

```
value.match(uservalue)
```

The line above makes the following: searches any uservalue in value variable and match it.
 
Working example is placed here: http://jsfiddle.net/nYVX4/

Comment: In your example "2" will return "The id exists" because it matched "21".

Answer (score 1):

you can create an array of values from the original rel value, and then check for a single value existence with inArray() method:

```
var values = $('a').attr('rel').split(' ');
alert ($.inArray(userSubmittedValue, values));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var values = $('a').attr('rel').split(' ');
```

and now your values array will contain all the values. Loop through the array and do comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```
var uservalue = $('input:text').val();

if ($('a[rel~="' + uservalue + '"]').length > 0) {
    alert('The id exists');
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

More: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/